# d3.js grid moving around when dragging and zooming

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, gridlines

I tried to copy the behavior of the grid displayed [here](http://static.cybercommons.org/js/d3/examples/zoom-pan/zoom-pan.html).

The code I have is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p4cmx1kj/1/)

Problem is, when I'm dragging or zooming, the grid is moving along with everything else, while it should not.

I suspect the problem is around this part :

```
function zoomed() {
          svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

Indeed, when I remove the last line, the grid works fine *(more or less)* :

```
function zoomed() {
          svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        }
```

**However**, in **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/p4cmx1kj/2/)** case, my visualization (the lines) don't move anymore:

How can I make my lines and the grid move the right way?

Comment: Your last fiddle link is incomplete.

Comment: Indeed : stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to post more than 2 links since I'm new here. But StuperUser fixed this apparently :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your code

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/p4cmx1kj/3/

You will need to update the lines also on zoom along with axis.

```
function zoomed() {
              svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
              svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
              lines.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }
```